# Sub slects within a case statement

Tags: sql

So I have declared a variable @Location. I want to return specific data from 1 column in a table based on the variable.

Like this...

IF @Location = 'Pennsylvania', then return all fields in this columns that begin with '123' 
IF @ Location = 'New York, then return the fields in this column that begin with '345' 
This is what I have written so far, not sure if I'm approaching this correctly...

```
 SELECT 

      CASE WHEN @Site = 'PEnnsylvania' THEN
 (
    SELECT A.so_prod_key 
    FROM so_prod_tbl A 
    WHERE A.so_prod_key LIKE '110%' 
  )   


 WHEN @Site = 'New York' THEN
  ( 
    SELECT B.so_prod_key 
    FROM so_prod_tbl B 
    WHERE B.so_prod_key LIKE '112%' 
  )


     WHEN @Site = 'New Jersey' THEN 
    ( 
        SELECT C.so_prod_key 
        FROM so_prod_tbl C 
        WHERE C.so_prod_key LIKE '111%' 
    )
    ELSE ' ' END AS 'Products'
```

A little guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Either MySQL or SQL-server, cannot be both. I've removed the conflicting tags, please add the correct one back in

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

That case expression can be changed like

```
 CASE WHEN @Site = 'PEnnsylvania' AND A.so_prod_key LIKE '110%' 
THEN A.so_prod_key ELSE NULL END As col1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT A.so_prod_key 
FROM so_prod_tbl A 
WHERE (@Site = 'Pennsylvania' and A.so_prod_key LIKE '110%') or
      (@Site = 'New York' and A.so_prod_key LIKE '112%') or
      (@Site = 'New Jersey' and A.so_prod_key LIKE '111%')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like the following, placing the case statement in a WHERE clause instead:

```
SELECT A.so_prod_key

FROM so_prod_tbl A

WHERE A.so_prod_key LIKE ( 

                            CASE 
                                    WHEN @Site = ‘Pennsylvania’ THEN ‘110%’
                                    WHEN @Site = ‘New York’ THEN ‘112%’
                                    —- etc.
                            END
                        )
;
```